# Survey123 info file not reflecting changes

Tags: arcgis-survey123

I am using Survey123 for collecting data. I am using Survey123 Connect for designing form. Now i have requirement to use one of our own map in survey123 for collecting geopoint.

After doing some research i came to know that custom maps can be added in tile map form. And to do so you have to modify .info file.

I did that as asked the problem is when i do a change and press save nothing happens of survey123 connect rather the info files gets back to its original state.